# Unusual behavior in ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

At first attempt of login user enter correct credentials but app routes to login again but I have redirect it to another controller action. After that when user attempts second login, it redirects to dashboard successfully but this time when user click any link it again redirect to login instead of expected route. But in third attempt all links are accessible I didn't understand whats going on please help

Routing configuration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace AdiSystem
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="UsersDBCcotext" connectionString="Server=hgws7.win.hostgator.com; User ID=begiqi_adi_; Password=Waleed4444; Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=begiqi_adi" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <!--<add name="UsersDBCcotext" connectionString="Data Source=VAIO\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=UsersDB4" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <!--<add name="UsersDBCcotext" connectionString="Server=hgws7.win.hostgator.com; User ID=begiqi_adi_; Password=Waleed4444; Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=begiqi_adi" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="UsersDBCcotext" connectionString="Data Source=DELL;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=UsersDB5" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Login Post Function

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Users ObjUsers)
{
    var EncryptedPassWord = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ObjUsers.Password);
    var UserCheck = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name == ObjUsers.Name && x.UserPassword == EncryptedPassWord ).FirstOrDefault();
    var UserAdmin = db.Admin.Where(x => x.Name == ObjUsers.Name && x.UserPassword == EncryptedPassWord).FirstOrDefault();

    if (UserCheck != null)
    {
        if (UserCheck.IsActive == true)
        {
            var profilerights = db.ProfileRights.Where(x => x.ProfileRightsId == 2).FirstOrDefault();

            if (profilerights != null)
            {
                WebUsersLogs.AccessFeatures = profilerights.GivenRights.Split(',').ToArray();
            }

            WebUsersLogs.UserID = UserCheck.UsersId;
            WebUsersLogs.User = UserCheck;

            return RedirectToAction("DiscussionsDash","User");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["msge"] = "Your Account has expired";
            TempData["MsgType"] = 0;

            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
    else if (UserAdmin != null)
    {
        var profilerights = db.ProfileRights.Where(x => x.ProfileRightsId == 1).FirstOrDefault();

        if (profilerights != null)
        {
            WebUsersLogs.AccessFeatures = profilerights.GivenRights.Split(',').ToArray();
        }

        WebUsersLogs.AdminId = UserAdmin.AdminId;
        WebUsersLogs.Admin = UserAdmin;

        return RedirectToAction("DiscussionsDash", "User");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["msge"] = "Username or Password is invalid";
        TempData["MsgType"] = 0;

        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can anyone help if you don't post any code?

Comment: brother its unusal behavior i didnt understand which code to post

Comment: in third attemp every thing is fine i think there is no error in my code

Comment: Well if you can isolate the problem code you are going to find a hard time finding help. good luck!

Comment: You should read [MCVE] which will explain techniques for isolating problematic code.

Comment: thank u for replying

Comment: brother i have share some of my code can u help me from this

Comment: What is `WebUsersLogs`? Where did that come from?